# how to use Synchronized Data Extensions in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I want to use the Synchronized Data Extensions in journey builder. How can I use it . Please provide me a steps to use it .

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You can't use Synchronized Data Extensions in Journey Buider. You have to duplicate the records in a Sendable Data Extension using a SQL in Automation Studio (or a Data filter) and then link it to the Data Model in Data Designer.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5) for more insights on the synchronized Data sourcesv and to this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLG0S.jpg) for comparaison between regular DE, Salesforce DE and Synchronized DE.

Comment: can you explain me deeply?